# Error with decoded CSV file: InvalidArgumentError: Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, apache-kafka

I am using Python 3.7.7, tensorflow-io version: 0.17.0 and tensorflow version: 2.4.0. I want to read CSV file from Kafka and use that data to train the model. The whole code can be found on https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/kafka and
https://github.com/tensorflow/io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/kafka.ipynb.

```
...
def decode_kafka_item(item):
  message = tf.io.decode_csv(item.message, [[0.0] for i in range(NUM_COLUMNS)])
  key = tf.strings.to_number(item.key)
  return (message, key)

BATCH_SIZE=64
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE=64
train_ds = tfio.IODataset.from_kafka('susy-train', partition=0, offset=0)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.map(decode_kafka_item)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
...
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

The error when the last line is issued is:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside
> [[{{node DecodeCSV}}]]
> [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_956]
>
> Function call stack:
> train_function

Questions with similar error presented have different code and are not answered.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This problem is only present on Windows OS. On Linux systems, there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Try replacing all the `CR` ('\r') and `LF` ('\n') while sending messages from producer side

So the Producer side code should look something like this:

```
def write_to_kafka(topic_name, items):
  count=0
  producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'])
  for message, key in items:
    message=message.split('\r')[0] #Removing all the '\r' from the string
    producer.send(topic_name, key=key.encode('utf-8'), value=message.encode('utf-8')).add_errback(error_callback)
    count+=1
  producer.flush()
  print("Wrote {0} messages into topic: {1}".format(count, topic_name))
```

**My Guess:**
I came to know about about this when i printed the message that was being sent by the producer which looked something like this:
`b'0,0,1,0,0,0\r'`
And since the error said:

> Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside
> So i just replaced all the CRLFs

I was facing the same issue on my Windows machine, and i saw some answers online in which the same example worked on Linux, I am guessing it's just the problem with Windows adding `CRLF`'s to the csv file,but this is just my guess not sure about the exact reason.